# Laravel 4 - Reuse controllers and views using routes

Tags: laravel, reusability, laravel-routing

I'm building a blog application with **Laravel 4** which has two types of users, the administrator and the regular user.

When users create their accounts or when they log in all of their routes have the **"user"** prefix , like this:

**GET user/posts  = PostsController@index**

For administrators all of their routes have the **"admin"** prefix , like so:

**GET admin/users = UsersController@index**

To view all the posts from a user as an administrator I do this:

**GET admin/users/($id)/posts = PostsController@index**

So if a regular user is logged then I get his **ID from session**, but if the user is an administrator then I get the regular user **ID from the url**.

I also have to update the links inside the views, like this:

As a regular user:   **link_to("user/posts/create", "Create Post")**

As an administrator: **link_to("admin/users/1/posts/create", "Create Post")**

Is there a better approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, all users are users.

Anything that requires you to be an administrator should have a filter for that on the route.

So for example, if an administrator was only allowed to go to `user/posts/delete/{id}`, that route would look something like...

```
Route::post('user/posts/delete/{id}', array('before' => 'adminFilter', 'uses' => 'PostController@deletePost');
```

I'm not sure how you figure out if a user is an admin or regular user, but your filter could look something like...

```
Route::filter('adminFilter', function()
{
    if (!Auth::user()->isAdmin())
    {
        return Redirect::to('home')->with('message', 'You aren't an admin!');
    }
});
```

And you would simply put an `isAdmin()` function in your `User` model which describes how to tell if a user is admin and returns true or false.